# Is it possible to use "Group by" concept in Realm mobile database

Tags: realm

I am new to Realm mobile DB and Just wanted to know that is Grouping concept which we use in oracle/sqlite possible in realm DB ?

Comment: As far as I know, it's still on the [wanted but not done](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/realm-cocoa/group/realm-cocoa/NRcYJNtrvd0/XOTcVCwUfV8J) list.

Comment: Well depending on use case, DISTINCT can be enough to build what you need

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2309

Answer (score 0):

Currently realm doesn't support group by concept like RDBMS , but the feature is nice to have to realm. 
i think realm adding the feature in their roadmap